# Good Way to Filter Object in a List Which A property Equal B property in Two Object

Tags: groovy

I have list of Objects(Name A), A have property B and C. I need to find the object in the list which B property equal with another object's C property. For Example:

```
def objectList = [A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8]; 
if A1.B == A2.C then return A1,A2;
```

Any good way to do that?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [findAll](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#findAll%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) method for this:

```
def list = []
def matching = list.findAll { A a ->
   a.B == a.C
}
```

**Update**

You can get all the pairs of matching objects this way:

```
def matching = []
list.unique { A a1, A a2 ->
    if (a1.B == a2.C || a1.C == a2.B) {
        matching << a1 << a2
    }
    return 1
}
```

This is kind of a hacky solution since it does not use the [unique](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#unique%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) method as intended.

Comment: Hi drorb, thanks for your reply. Maybe I am not describe my case clearly. I hope compare one object's A property is equal to another object's B property or not. If yes, then return those two object.

Comment: I think you should update the question and provide an example of what you expect after comparing all the list objects

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have update the question, hope it can make the issue more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you want your result flattened or not, anyway here's a solution returning a list of tuples:

```
def result = list.inject([]) {acc,a1->
    list.each {a2->
        if (!a1.is(a2)  && a1.b == a2.c) {
            acc << [a1,a2]
        }
    }
    acc
}
```